# How to specify a "deliverables after payment" clause?

Tags: contracts, payment-terms, software

I am keen to avoid situations (as I have had in the past) where I hand over source code, and am not paid until significantly later. I'm perfectly happy to demonstrate that the work has been done, but I would like, at the least to specify that they can not legally use the work until it is paid for.

Is there any standard wording for this? Either:

- "I will demonstrate the work, but you can't have the source code until I receive payment"; or
- "I will give you the code, but you can't do anything with it other than assess it until I receive payment".

Is this uncommon or unreasonable?

Comment: What jurisdiction are you from? Also, common to me is part in advance and part after delivery, would that work for you also?

Comment: Australia. Yeah, I think I will start doing that, too.

Comment: @BCLC wrong site?

Answer (score 2):

It is common and completely reasonable. At least the source code delivery part. The *"not do anything with it"* isn't really common. If clients aren't permitted to do anything with the source code, **don't** deliver it.

Common phraseology:

> Delivery upon receipt of full payment

or

> .... to be delivered subsequent to final payment

Comment: Well, they would be permitted to evaluate it for the purpose of deciding whether to make the final payment yet.

Comment: I, personally, fail to see how that's a viable business model -- "Here's everything you need... by the way pay me now." Clients customarily *pay* before delivery, then evaluate. You don't eat at a restaurant, dislike the food and THEN decide you aren't paying. You pay either way.

Comment: But you *do* test drive a car before paying for it.

Comment: And clients can "test drive" an app/web site/whatever **without** source code.

Comment: Maybe. If deployment is not part of the contract, and if it's entirely front-end with no obfuscation step in the build, then that's not really true. (Both true in this case.)

Comment: Car is a good example. Usually you have to pay before starting using it. Depends highly on jurisdiction and industry though!

Comment: Well I've never heard of anything like that in the US. In fact "test drives" are very, very common before purchasing a vehicle. Almost to the point of them being *mandatory*.